# get value in input field from virtual keyboard in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a countdown watch which have a virtual numpad (given in code as button) and three input (hour,minute and second). now i want that whenever i click input box and type in virtual numpad ,it print the value in that box only.

1. there i used three ref to getElement of input and change set their value but dont know how to set for specific box

```
const inputOne = useRef(null);
const inputTwo = useRef(null);
const inputThree = useRef(null);

  const changeValue = (val) => {
    inputOne.current.value  = setTime({hour: updatedHour + val, minute: updatedMinute, second: updatedSecond}); 
    inputTwo.current.value = setTime({hour: updatedHour, minute: updatedMinute + val, second: updatedSecond});
    inputThree.current.value = setTime({hour: updatedHour, minute: updatedMinute, second: updatedSecond + val}); 
    }

const changeTime = (e) => {
    setTime({ ...time, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

2. this is input fields i use , updatedHour,updatedMinute and updatedSecond is part of setTime state.

```
  <input ref={props.inputOne} onChange={props.changeTime} name="hour"  placeholder="Hour"  value={props.updatedHour} />
          <input ref={props.inputTwo} onChange={props.changeTime} name="minute"  placeholder="Minute" value={props.updatedMinute} />
          <input ref={props.inputThree} onChange={props.changeTime} name="second"  placeholder="Second" value={props.updatedSecond} />
```

3. this is buttons which create virtual keyboard

```
 <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('1')}>1</button>
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('2')}>2</button>
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('3')}>3</button>  
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('4')}>4</button>
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('5')}>5</button>
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('6')}>6</button>  
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('7')}>7</button>
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('8')}>8</button>
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('9')}>9</button>  
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' >Prev</button>  
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' onClick={()=> props.changeValue('0')}>0</button>  
  <button className="grid-item" tpye='button' >Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied whatever you've been writing and added it to `stackblitz`, and I've added some changes to it the link is below, hope you find it useful:

[link to stackblitz for the solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tcretv?file=src/App.js)